# Error creating cluster using eks anywhere

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create a local cluster on a centos7 machine using eks anywhere. However I am getting below error. Please let me know if I am missing anything? Here is the link I am following to create the cluster. I have also attached the cluster create yaml file

Link:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-eks-anywhere-now-generally-available-to-create-and-manage-kubernetes-clusters-on-premises/

Error:
Error: failed to create cluster: error waiting for external etcd for workload cluster to be ready: error executing wait: error: timed out waiting for the condition on clusters/dev-cluster

[clustercreate yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUbVt.png)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default spec will look for external etcd. To test it locally remove the `externalEtcdConfiguration`:

```
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: dev-cluster
spec:
  clusterNetwork:
    cni: cilium
    pods:
      cidrBlocks:
      - 192.168.0.0/16
    services:
      cidrBlocks:
      - 10.96.0.0/12
  controlPlaneConfiguration:
    count: 1
  datacenterRef:
    kind: DockerDatacenterConfig
    name: dev-cluster
  kubernetesVersion: "1.21"
  workerNodeGroupConfigurations:
  - count: 1
---
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: DockerDatacenterConfig
metadata:
  name: dev-cluster
spec: {}
---
```

Comment: Thanks for response. After removing the external etcd configuration, I don't that error now. However cluster creation is stuck at below and its like this for more than 30 minutes

Comment: Here is the verbose output:


2021-09-15T20:09:04.729-0700    V6      Executing command       {"cmd": "/usr/bin/docker run -i --network host -v /root:/root -w /root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --entrypoint kubectl public.ecr.aws/eks-anywhere/cli-tools:v0.1.0-eks-a-1 wait --timeout 60m --for=condition=ControlPlaneReady clusters.cluster.x-k8s.io/dev-cluster --kubeconfig dev-cluster/generated/dev-cluster.kind.kubeconfig -n eksa-system"}

Comment: To avoid mixing up different issues in one question, can you accept the answer and start a new question with all the debug messages you have?

Comment: Sure, I will create a new one with debug messages